# Multiply a value based on a select box options

Tags: javascript

I have a small form with fixed costs based on where they are shipping from and going to with how many pallets.

For example UK Zone 1 to France Zone 1 = 20
Also UK Zone 3 to France Zone 4 = 68

```
var values = [
        [20,25,35,40],
        [36,42,50,56],
        [42,56,52,68],
        [60,70,68,72]
    ];
```

What i'm trying to achieve now is how would I multiply that total value.

So for example if the user selects UK Zone 1 going to France Zone 1 that is = £20 for 1 product

But if they select 2 from the select box the total cost should now be £40

Here is where I have got to but I cant get it to work

```
function updateValue() {
        var fromCountry = document.querySelector('input[name="from_country"]:checked').value;
        var toCountry = document.querySelector('input[name="to_country"]:checked').value;

        var totalValues = values[fromCountry-1][toCountry-1];
        var fixValues = document.querySelector('select[name="number"]');
        var n = parseInt(fixValues.val(), 10);

        if(fromCountry && toCountry) {
            document.getElementById('cost').value = (totalValues * n);
        }
    }
```

Full Fiddle Here - http://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/ZXHbq/3/

Help badly needed :-)

Comment: Why do you take the value of `toCountry` as `document.querySelector('..').value` and `fixValues` as `document.querySelector('..').val()` ?

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't contain the whole code to be tested.

Comment: Im not sure to be honest. I was working off this example - http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/enKV6/ I am probably way off..

Comment: MelanciaUK - Just updated the fiddle.

Comment: really need to learn to use browser console to check for errors thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` is jQuery function. Since you don't use jQuery, use `fixValues.value`. And don't forget to make a call `updateValue()`, which is missing in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to get it working:

```
function updateValue() {
        var fromCountry = document.querySelector('input[name="from_country"]:checked').value;
        var toCountry = document.querySelector('input[name="to_country"]:checked').value;

        var totalValues = values[fromCountry-1][toCountry-1];
        var fixValues = document.querySelector('select[name="number"]');
        var n = parseInt(fixValues.value, 10);

        if(fromCountry && toCountry) {
            document.getElementById('cost').value = (totalValues * n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would anyone have any idea why this calculation isnt working in IE8. I thought it was just to do with the :checked pseudo class. but when I took this out the calculation doesnt work [http://redhead-int.com/rednet/daily-pallet-service.php](http://redhead-int.com/rednet/daily-pallet-service.php)